# Get-MsolUser command error from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure

I am trying to execute a piece of Azure script to check if the user object is synced from on-prem AD to Azure as below.

username follows the pattern of a `UPN`. example: `john.Smith@ed.com`

```
 //Check Azure to see if user is synced to office 365
        private static bool IsAccountSyncedToOffice365(string username)
        {
            StringBuilder cmd = CreateAzureConnectScript();
            //cmd.AppendLine("Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName " + username + " -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue");
            cmd.AppendLine("$global:res = \"false\"");
            cmd.AppendLine("$global:user = \"false\"");
            cmd.AppendLine("try{ if(($global:user=Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName " + username + " -ErrorAction Stop).ImmutableId -ne $null) { $global:res = \"true\"} } Catch { $global:errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message}");

            try
            {
                Collection<PSObject> results;
                string output, error, errorMessageAzureCnn = "";

                do
                {
                    results = null;
                    output = "";
                    error = "";
                    var rs = CreateAzureRunspace();
                    var pipe = rs.CreatePipeline();
                    pipe.Commands.AddScript(cmd.ToString());

                    results = pipe.Invoke();

                    output = (rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("res")) != null ? rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("res").ToString() : "false";
                    error = (rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("errorMessage")) != null ? rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("errorMessage").ToString() : "null";
                    errorMessageAzureCnn = (rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("errorMessageAzureCnn")) != null ? rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("errorMessageAzureCnn").ToString() : "null";
                    ExceptionManager.Publish(new Exception("LOG: Queried Azure at:" + DateTime.Now + " for user:" + username + " Result: " + output + " Error: " + error + " errorMessageAzureCnn: " + errorMessageAzureCnn));

                    Thread.Sleep(60000); //sleep for 60 seconds
                    pipe.Dispose();
                    rs.Close();
                    rs.Dispose();

                } while (output.Trim().ToLower() != "true");

                ExceptionManager.Publish(new Exception("LOG: " + username + " is found synced to Azure at: " + DateTime.Now));

                cmd.Clear();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.Publish(new Exception("Error checking Azure to see if the user is synced to office 365 or not.. " + ex.Message));
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

---

```
private static StringBuilder CreateAzureConnectScript()
{
    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();
    MSCredential cred = new MSCredential();

    var username = cred.username;
    var pwd = cred.password;

    try
    {
        ss.AppendLine("try {");
        ss.AppendLine("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"" + pwd + "\" -AsPlainText –Force");
        ss.AppendLine("$credential = New-Object  System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(\"" + username + "\",$password)");
        ss.AppendLine("$cred = Get-Credential -cred $credential");
        ss.AppendLine("Import-Module MSOnline");
        ss.AppendLine("Start-Sleep -s 10");
        ss.AppendLine("Connect-Msolservice -cred $cred");
        ss.AppendLine("} Catch { $global:errorMessageAzureCnn = $_.Exception.Message }");

        //ExceptionManager.Publish(new Exception("LOG:pwd: " + pwd + " uname:" + username));

        return ss;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionManager.Publish(new Exception("Error enabling the remote mailbox.. " + ex.Message));
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

While the script executes successfully through Powershell Window on the same server having got all the latest versions of the modules installed. When trying to execute the same command from C# code it throws the below exception collected from the powershell exception handling  `$global:errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message`.

Show Details Exception (0): [] LOG: Queried Azure at:7/30/2015 12:00:55 PM for user:testuser0385@xxx.com Result: false Error: `You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets`. errorMessageAzureCnn: null

Worth mentioning that I have got the same code as below working in one server but it is throwing the below error on a production server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter) and only via the code it is happening. via the powershell window it works perfectly fine.

Good to know your thoughts about what looks wrong or needed to be looked into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It suggests that the sign in is failing, but you're pushing on with the Get-MsolUser anyway. The Connect-MsolService cmdlet fails if it cannot communicate to the Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant. Ref: https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/252201

Has the production server got all the pre-requisites installed: Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant and .NET 3.5? We had a problem in production (Azure PAAS) where the guest OS image was automatically updated and was missing .NET 3.5, which broke our Azure AD PowerShell processes.